# Redirect URL while updating product status dynamically

Tags: product-list, status, redirect-url, product-edit, product-grid

I am making a custom module like market place, anyone can become seller and he will have facility in his account to add products and sell them. And he will be able to see all the related functionality in the same account, to manage this i have used `Customer Group` and created a customer under that group.

Now, in admin panel admin will see all the products uploaded by all the sellers, he will review those products and click on approve/Unapprove accordingly.

To achieve this, i have used ajax to make approve/Unapprove work properly.

**The problem i am facing:**
I want admin to redirect on products edit mode when he clicks on approve link. After that he will edit whatever he wants to and then click on save, so as he clicks on same i want product status to be enabled.

I am attaching a screenshot of my product grid.
[image: Here is my product grid]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product edit URL via following method :

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $productId]))
```

You'll need to replace $productId accordingly. In a grid where you are showing this info, you should be having this as part of grid row properties.

Comment: Okay, let me try that and i will get back to you, thanx for the prompt reply.